# Function on open disc proof

Tags: analysis

> Prove that a continuous real valued function on an open disc that has a single zero at the center of the disc must be either always positive away from the zero, or always negative

So we have a function $f(x,y)$ defined on $D = \{(x,y):x^2+y^2 <1\}$ where $f(0,0)=0$ is the only zero for our function.

The fact that we are working on a domain on the disc is hindering my advancement. The idea makes intuitive sense, but I am not sure how to show this. I had the idea to perhaps argue proof by contradiction and use the intermediate value theorem, but I am not certain if this applies on the open disc.

Any hints or help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f(n) < 0 < f(p)$ where $n,p \in D$.

We know that neither $n,p$ are the origin. Let $\gamma$ be a continuous path from $n$ to $p$ that does not pass through $0$. Since $f\circ \gamma ([0,1])$ is connected we must have some $t \in (0,1)$ such that $f(\gamma(t)) = 0$, which is a contradiction.

There are many ways to construct such a path. One way is to start at $n$ and rotate around the origin until one hits the ray from $0$ that passes through $p$ and then
join to $p$ be a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove  the origin from the disk you get a connected set. Continuous image of a connected set is connected. Since the image of the punctured disk is an interval in the real line, if it contains both positive and negative values it would contain $0$ contradicting the hypothesis.